# Chrome Native Client and memory-mapped file

Tags: google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I would like to build a Chrome multimedia extension.

I would like this extension to communicate with another process (using a "memory-mapped file" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx). Is it possible?

From the NaCl FAQ:

> If I want direct access to the OS, should I use Native Client?
>
> No—Native Client does not provide direct access to the OS or devices,
>   or otherwise bypass the JavaScript security model. For more
>   information, see later sections of this FAQ.

If it is not possible to use memory-mapped files in NaCl's sandbox, is there any other way to build such plugin?

My extension would be used only by me, so I can accept security flaws.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. The sandbox is designed to prevent that kind of thing. The only way to use APIs other than the Pepper APIs (or of course those available in JavaScript) would be to install a native app in the OS, and communicate with it from a web app or extension using Native Messaging:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging (that might be a good solution for you since it sounds like communicating with another process is what you want to do anyway).